# Jframe window doesn't open with my executable jar

Tags: swing, jframe, java

i just made a basic calculator project in netbeans, and when i run the project there the code works just fine, and when i go to docs> netbeans projects>dist>calculator.jar, and run it there it works but when i drag that to desktop and try to run it there the JFrame won't open

here is the only class below:

```
package calculator;

/**
 *
 * @author David
 */
public class ui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form ui
     */
    public ui() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jScrollBar1 = new javax.swing.JScrollBar();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        addBut = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        subBut = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        mulBut = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        divBut = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        intOneText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        intTwoText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        result = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        goButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout()); // error here

        jLabel1.setText("Calculator");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(110, 60, -1, -1));

        buttonGroup1.add(addBut);
        addBut.setText("Add");
        getContentPane().add(addBut, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(200, 110, -1, -1));

        buttonGroup1.add(subBut);
        subBut.setText("Subtract");
        getContentPane().add(subBut, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(260, 110, -1, -1));

        buttonGroup1.add(mulBut);
        mulBut.setText("Multiply");
        getContentPane().add(mulBut, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(200, 140, -1, -1));

        buttonGroup1.add(divBut);
        divBut.setText("Divide");
        getContentPane().add(divBut, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(280, 140, -1, -1));
        getContentPane().add(intOneText, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(89, 131, 83, -1));
        getContentPane().add(intTwoText, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(90, 180, 83, -1));

        jLabel2.setText("Integer 1:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 134, -1, -1));

        jLabel3.setText("Integer 2:");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 180, -1, -1));

        result.setText("Solution Will Appear Here");
        getContentPane().add(result, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(180, 220, -1, -1));

        goButton.setText("Calculate");
        goButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                goButtonMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(goButton, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(59, 218, -1, -1));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void goButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

        if(intOneText.getText().equals("")){
             result.setText("Something is missing here...");
         }
         if(intTwoText.getText().equals("")){
             result.setText("Something is missing here...");
         }

        String intOne = intOneText.getText();
        float numOne = Float.parseFloat(intOne);
        String intTwo = intTwoText.getText();
        float numTwo = Float.parseFloat(intTwo);
        float answer = 0;

        boolean addTrue = false;
        boolean subTrue = false;
        boolean mulTrue = false;
        boolean divTrue = false;


        if(addBut.isSelected()){
            addTrue = true;
            subTrue = false;
            mulTrue = false;
            divTrue = false;
        }

        if(subBut.isSelected()){
            addTrue = false;
            subTrue = true;
            mulTrue = false;
            divTrue = false;
        }

        if(mulBut.isSelected()){
            addTrue = false;
            subTrue = false;
            mulTrue = true;
            divTrue = false;
        }

        if(divBut.isSelected()){
            addTrue = false;
            subTrue = false;
            mulTrue = false;
            divTrue = true;
        }

        if(addTrue == false){
            if(subTrue == false){
                if(mulTrue == false){
                    if(divTrue == false){
                         result.setText("Something is missing here...");
                    }
                }
            }
        }


       if(addTrue == true){
           answer = numOne + numTwo;
       }
       if(subTrue == true){
           answer = numOne - numTwo;
       }
       if(mulTrue == true){
           answer = numOne * numTwo;
       }
       if(divTrue == true){
           answer = numOne / numTwo;
       }

       result.setText(Float.toString(answer));

    }                                     

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ui().setVisible(true);


            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton addBut;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton divBut;
    private javax.swing.JButton goButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField intOneText;
    private javax.swing.JTextField intTwoText;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollBar jScrollBar1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton mulBut;
    private javax.swing.JLabel result;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton subBut;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The error that i get in the command line is:

Exception in thread"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/awtExtra/AbsoluteLayout

at line 44... (commented above)

Comment: Copy the jar to a folder somewhere. Go to the command line, go to the same folder and use `java -jar calculator.jar` note the error. I beat it's missing a depended library (namely the swing layout library that's required for the `AbsoluteLayout`

Comment: Error: Unable to access jarfile calculator.jar

Comment: sorry i put in the wrong jar file

Comment: `org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints` Uggh..  That is as almost as bad as using a `null` layout and `setBounds()`.  Use combinations of other layout managers that might honor the *preferred size* of the components and adjust location & size according to *available space.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to double-click the JAR file?  Because that won't work.

You have to open up a cmd and type:
java -jar calculator.jar

I think it's case sensitive, so CALCULATOR.JAR won't work.  You need the .jar extension.

There is a way to make it executable via doubleclicking but that requires extra steps.

Good luck!

Comment: If configured correctly, double-click a JAR file should work fine. The OP is asking for specific reasons why this won't work on his system.

Comment: i got an error but my command prompt is acting weird, it says that i cannot find the path desktop from my user account

Comment: @CodeLover Please edit your question to include the exact error message.

Comment: The error that i get in the command propmt is: Error: Unable to access jarfile calculator.jar

Comment: Note: the problem was i had the layout setup as an absolute layout when it was free design